# How to create an `All` option in drop down menu

Tags: php

The drop down menu below displays options where the value of each option is the `StudentId` from th database:

```
<select name="student" id="studentsDrop">
<?php
while ( $currentstudentstmt->fetch() ) {
$stu = $dbStudentId;
if(isset($_POST["student"]) && $stu == $_POST["student"]) 
    echo "<option selected='selected' value='$stu'>" . $dbStudentAlias . " - " . $dbStudentForename . " " . $dbStudentSurname . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo "<option value='$stu'>" . $dbStudentAlias . " - " . $dbStudentForename . " " . $dbStudentSurname . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
</select>
```

But what my question is how do I display an `All` option where if the user selects this, then the value for this option will be for all student ids.

The code which generates the students values are here:

Comment: @OneTrickPony Wouldn't that find student's with a student id of `all`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it there yourself:

```
echo "<option>All</option>";
while ( $currentstudentstmt->fetch() ) {
```

You can do the same `_POST['student']` check to see if `All` is selected as well.

Comment: Would that look for all students from the database if I create option like this?

Comment: @user1830984 No you would have to do an explicit check on `if ($_POST['student'] == 'All')` and not use the specific student ID in the query

Comment: Oh so you are saying create two queries, one query for All where it does not have a where clause for studentid, else do the other query where it contains a WHERE clause for specific student id

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you would use special value ("ALL" or "" or something similar) to indicate that all ids were requested